# CLOUD FOUNDRY API [ ORGS & SPACES ]

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry

Cloud Foundry user access getting revoked within 24 hour once assigned for a particular SPACE in an ORG
Currently Using 
Version:
cf-277
diego1.27.0

I have tried investigating through cf-api with the following command 
[ audit.user.space_developer_remove ]

```
cf-api [ audit.user.space_developer_remove ]

{
            "metadata": {
                "guid": "guid",
                "url": "/",
                "created_at": "2019-03-14T06:06:16Z",
                "updated_at": "2019-03-14T06:06:16Z"
            },
            "entity": {
                "type": "audit.user.space_developer_remove",
                "actor": "cf-management",
                "actor_type": "user",
                "actor_name": "",
                "actor_username": "",
                "actee": "actee_id",
                "actee_type": "user",
                "actee_name": "",
                "timestamp": "2019-03-14T06:06:16Z",
                "metadata": {
                    "request": {}
                },
                "space_guid": "space_guid",
                "organization_guid": "org_guid"
            }
```

Got this as result in which i have no clue of the Parameter actor:"cf-management" and other user related information.

Unable to identify why the access is getting revoked with this piece of info.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your PCF Ops / Cloud Ops team is using the [cf-mgmt](https://github.com/pivotalservices/cf-mgmt) pipeline for setting up orgs, and spaces. The pipeline can grant access to users to an org and/or space.

This is provisioning by automation.

My guess is there is some mismatch. Please reach out to your PCF Ops / Cloud Ops team and discuss this issue with them.